# use same image in wordpress gallery without upload it many times

Tags: wordpress, image, grid, gallery

I know this sounds strange but I need to make a gallery with repeated images.

I need to know if is possible to use the same image in the gallery more than one time without having to add it again and again. It's very annoying to have the same image repeated many times among the uploaded images.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use the same uploaded image many times in different galleries. simply chose them from the Mediathek instead of upload. or do you want to use the same image several times in the same gallery?

Comment: @Beatroot, yes, I want to use it in the same gallery

Comment: Is this just to test the responsiveness of your design, or will you be using the same image to fill in blank spots long term (like a repeating advertisement)?

Answer (score 0):

No, not with with orginal wordpress code. Even manually putting several times the same media-id will result in only one image being rendered. you can, however, create your own gallery shortcode: [code from here](https://snippets.khromov.se/override-wordpress-gallery-shortcode-with-your-own-shortcode/)

```
//Init hook
add_action('init', 'override_gallery');

//Override function
function override_gallery()
{
    remove_shortcode('gallery');
    add_shortcode('gallery', 'my_gallery_shortcode');
}

//Custom gallery shortcode
function my_gallery_shortcode($atts, $content) {

    //Default parameters to 
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
            'ids' => '',
            'orderby' => 'post__in',
            'columns' => '3',
            'link' => 'file' //file | link | <empty string> (for linking to attachment page)
    ), $atts ));

    //Your own presentational code here...
}
```

But you still can't choose the same image several times in the image selector. But you could multiply it in your shortcode. Probably it's better to create your own shortcode using another name though.